# how many ram does my computer support?

Tags: laptop, memory

I have been trying figuring out how many ram can my laptop handle.

This is the specification:
This is my laptop specification:

- Operating System
  Windows 8.1 64-bit
- CPU
  Intel Core i5 6300HQ @ 2.30GHz  47 °C
  Skylake 14nm Technology
- RAM
  8.00GB Dual-Channel Unknown @ 1063MHz (15-15-15-36)
  -Motherboard
  TR ST-S (U3E1)  51 °C
  -Graphics
  Generic PnP Monitor (1920x1080@60Hz)
  Intel (CLEVO/KAPOK Computer)
  2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 965M (CLEVO/KAPOK Computer)   49 °C
  ForceWare version: 385.41
  SLI Disabled
- Storage
  465GB Seagate ST500LM021-1KJ152 (SATA)  45 °C
- Optical Drives
  No optical disk drives detected
- Audio
  NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM)

my laptop lately has been running super slow,i need this information to find out how many i need.Thanks

Comment: The RAM limit is set by the motherboard: its specifications will tell you what the limit is.

Comment: To find those specifications check your Manual. For Notebooks its common to only support 2 modules. With 8 GB you might already have 2 x 4GB installed.

Comment: Your computer had no reason to run slow with that hardware. If slowness is the issue, look into cleaning your PC with CCleaner, glary utilities, disk cleanup, defrag, registry (CCleaner, make sure you backup). Make sure your PC isn't overheating, clean out any dust in fans.

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model for your laptop? You can usually find that information at the manufacturer's support website. Alternatively, since the motherboard determines the maximum amount of memory supported, you can check at the motherboard manufacturer's website. If you [open a command prompt window](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win8/cmd_prompt.php) and type `wmic baseboard get product,manufacturer,model` then hit the Enter key what do you see?

Comment: @xR34P3Rx That's a slow hard drive. Also, defrag and registry cleanups do next to nothing for system speed and are NOT recommended because they have a high chance of causing serious issues when used without knowing what they are doing.